# Rescan network with nmcli

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, nmcli

I am writing a small script to continuously scan wifi network. I am using nmcli for that purpose :

`nmcli device wifi list`

I periodically (every x seconds ) call this command in my script to search for a given network.

But I have noticed that sometimes I have to rescan the network to update the list of discovered networks :

`nmcli device wifi rescan`

It is not clear how often I have to do that. When do I need to rescan the network ?

Comment: are there any hidden networks?

Comment: have you gone through `man nmcli` for `wifi rescan` guidelines `but in some cases it can be useful
           to start scanning manually (e.g. after resuming the computer). By using ssid, it is
           possible to scan for a specific SSID, which is useful for APs with hidden SSIDs. You
           can provide multiple ssid parameters in order to scan more SSIDs.`

Comment: no there is no hidden network.

Answer (score 2):

```
nmcli dev wifi list --rescan yes
```

This will refresh the scan results.

Answer (score 0):

By default it seems that the system takes 30 seconds to perform another rescan.

> By default, nmcli ensures that the access point list is no older than 30 seconds and triggers a network scan if necessary. The --rescan can be used to either force or disable the scan regardless of how fresh the access point list is.

Took from [nmcli page](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html)

So if you want something faster than 30 seconds, you should run the rescan